# Performance of REST frameworks (Java vs PHP vs other)

Tags: java, php, performance, web-services, rest

We need to create a RESTful service. We're wondering which of the existing framework to choose. We know Java and PHP, so we mainly considering frameworks for these two, but other options are also possible.

Do you guys have any experience with the performance of different REST frameworks? Are there any huge differences? Are there any frameworks very heavy and we should avoid them if we care a lot about the performance?

All your thoughts would be very appreciated!

Comment: Apart from support REST what else do you need to do, that is going to be the deciding factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give [PlayFramework](http://www.playframework.org/) a try. In it's version 1.x it is really simple to use and it has a really small server footprint.

Comment: +1 For Playframework. Particularly the routing for RESTful URLs is so easy to accomplish. You can have a running prototype of your REST structure in less than half an hour.

Answer (score -3):

Personally from experience, I feel it would be easier for you to set up a REST framework in PHP than Java. Give [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) a try.

However, I don't feel PHP or Java are the best languages out there for this. If possible, try looking into Node.js or Ruby.

Comment: I'm not a Java fan, in fact I hate the language but if you're saying that Ruby is BETTER than a language that's been tested, used for various projects where performance is imperative, has the best VM in the world and various op-code performance-related optimizations - my friend, you just have no idea what you're talking about. -1 is for being completely off the radar with the answer. Codeigniter is a framework, not a REST framework. Please, before making claims such as what language is "better", make sure you include the context as well.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been vague in my original answer. I was suggesting that the OP use CI's MVC framework to build a RESTful service on top of.

Edit: Re. the choice of Java vs. Ruby, that is a personal opinion. Hence the "I feel" in front of that sentence.